# Lines in epsfig have corners

Tags: diagrams, xfig

I have a problem with epsfig. I want to draw some graphs.
I created the picture with xfig and got the following code:

```
\setlength{\unitlength}{4144sp}%
%
\begingroup\makeatletter\ifx\SetFigFont\undefined%
\gdef\SetFigFont#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \reset@font\fontsize{#1}{#2pt}%
  \fontfamily{#3}\fontseries{#4}\fontshape{#5}%
  \selectfont}%
\fi\endgroup%
\begin{picture}(2280,2011)(1336,-1925)
\thinlines
{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\put(1801,-61){\line( 1,-1){900}}
\put(2701,-961){\line(-1, 0){900}}
\end{picture}
```

I included it with the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\input{*/File.tex} 

\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is: The lines seem off, they are kind of irregular.

Comment: Your question seems unrelated to epsfig (the epsfig latex package has been obsolete for 20 years) you seem to be using the xfig driver that produces latex picture mode, this can only make very approximate shapes, you want to use the one that makes two files, an eps file with all the lines, and a .tex file with _just_ the text.